# Fail to run tests and get 'Some of your tests did a full page reload!'

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have a component which it's all responsibility is to make a check against url, and if based on that makes redirection to 2 different routes based on the url:

```
export class MyComp implements OnInit {

      isAuth: string
    
      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private authService: AuthService) {}
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getQueryString()
        this.authService.isAuthenticated.subscribe(authenticated => (this.isAuth = authenticated))
      }
    
      getQueryString() {
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Token) => {
          if (!params['access_token']) {
            this.authService.isAuthenticated('false')
            window.location.href = '/auth/login'
    
            return
          }
          localStorage.setItem('authHeader', JSON.stringify(params))
          window.location.href = `${window.location.pathname}/myroute`
        })
      }
    }
```

and in my tests is the following:

```
describe('MyComp', () => {
  let component: MyComp;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComp>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ MyComp ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComp);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But when I ran the tests it fails and I get this error in the stack trace: `Some of your tests did a full page reload!'`

I have searched about a fix but didn't really find anything, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am thinking it is the `window.location.href` but what is strange is you don't have any mocks for `AuthService` and `ActivatedRoute`.

Comment: Any idea? @AliF50

Comment: No still no idea, sorry.